# Node js app crashed on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy simple node js app on heroku but I am getting an error of application not running. Below is application logs:

[Application log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G08ZK.png)

Comment: Can you provide your package.json and your Profile?

Comment: Here is my package.json file:
{
  "name": "web-dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Web Dev",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Avni",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Comment: Ok, sorry I did a typo on my comment. I did mean "Procfile" and not "Profile". Do you have a Procfile?

Comment: Here is the content of Profile:

web: node server.js

Comment: Thanks. There was a typo in connectionString to connect to mongodb.

Comment: @Avni did you solvce it ?